# Why won't jsfiddle let me access document.body?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Any idea what's wrong with this?

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = 'test';

document.body.appendChild(p);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qaym3/

Comment: As the others have pointed out, but not exactly explained, your jsFiddle's config was putting your JavaScript code into the `<head>` (on the left, in the **Frameworks & Extensions** - *No wrap - in `<head>`*), so the `<body>` hasn't been parsed and isn't available to manipulate/traverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's no body yet.

Set the JS to run `onDomready` or `onLoad`.

Comment: What strikes me as odd is the fact that jsFiddle does in fact default to onLoad - the OP would have had to manually change the JS configuration to "in <head>", which is just about the only possible way to cause such a situation without modifying the JS, and something that couldn't conceivably have been an accident.

Comment: FWIW, there is a DOM, but no `body`.

Comment: @FelixKling Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

Because your Javascript was running before the document was ready.

On the left hand side switch the drop down to `onDomready` and you should be good.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Qaym3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Because your javascript was loaded before the body so document.body is still NULL. Rather use the unload method

```
window.onload = function() {
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = 'test';
document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qaym3/3/